# run Matlab commands one by one on windows using .bat file

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file

I am trying to run a function on different files; I would like to use Bash-Like script to do that. When I looked on the web; I found that I can use .bat file.

My .bat file contains this

```
matlab -bodesktop -nosplash -r myFunction('input_1.txt')
matlab -bodesktop -nosplash -r myFunction('input_2.txt')
matlab -bodesktop -nosplash -r myFunction('input_3.txt')
matlab -bodesktop -nosplash -r myFunction('input_4.txt')
matlab -bodesktop -nosplash -r myFunction('input_5.txt')
```

When I double click the file, it seems that these commands are running on parallel, which, makes the PC to crash.

I looked on Matlab Forum for alternative solutions, but couldn't work with me

Another option I found:

```
start -wait matlab -bodesktop -nosplash -r "myFunction('input_1.txt');exit"
..
```

Anyone used this before ?

Comment: All things aside, I'm pretty sure it should spell `-nosplash`.

Comment: [You have to use the -wait option for matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22307518/2732801).

Comment: Didn't work Daniel, I am using Windows

Comment: @user3378649: [It is for windows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html)

Comment: If one of the answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question. If your question is not answered, please explain what’s missing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two matlab binaries, one `matlabroot/bin` the other in `matlabroot/bin/win64/`. The first one is only a launcher application which typically terminates as soon as the main application is started successfully. To keep it open until the main application terminates you have to use the `-wait` option with your `matlab.exe` (not to be confused with the `start -wait` option, bot can be used together).

In your case try:

```
matlab -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -r myFunction('input_1.txt')
```

(I assume you intended to use "nodesktop").

All start parameters for windows are explained [here in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html). (You have to click "option1...optionN" to expand the relevant section.)

Answer (score -2):

First check that you have the option spelled correctly. [Click here for the options.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html)

Try this:

`matlab -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -r "myFunction('input_1.txt')"`

Edit:

By default, when you call the matlab command from a script, the command starts MATLAB and then immediately executes the next statements in the script. The -wait option pauses the script until MATLAB terminates.

Use the -wait option in a startup script to process the results from MATLAB. Calling MATLAB with this option blocks the script from continuing until the results are generated.

Comment: While this answer might contain the correct code, it does not explain the problem.