# Batch file calling executable does not print to terminal

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that starts an executable that is supposed to

1. Run a Matlab script and wait until it stops
2. Run an exe that does
       some work, print some output, and saves some data to disk and wait
       until it stops
3. Run another Matlab script

Item number one works fine. Item number two does not show console output. How can I fix that.

This is my script

```
start /wait matlab -r start.m
start /wait "c/hello.exe"
start matlab -r finish.m
```

Comment: It doesn't show output or it never gets executed? Do you have an `exit()` call at the end of `start.m`?

Comment: @Suever There is an exit in both m files. The exe does not show terminal output nor does it write a file. So I cannot tell if it executed or not (probably not)

Comment: Can you put a print statement at the end of the MATLAB script to make sure it finishes? It could be that it is erroring out.

Comment: @Suever the matlab files are running at the same time, hence the exe is running too because it's in the middle

Comment: That `/wait` you have in there ensures that they *aren't* running at the same time. Each one will not be executed until the previous one exits.

Comment: @Suever This is not what is going on. All three items are running together.

Comment: [You have to use the `-wait` parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687254/run-matlab-commands-one-by-one-on-windows-using-bat-file/35687469#35687469)

Comment: But you *want* it to wait? What about using the [`-wait` input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495/how-can-i-stop-matlab-from-returning-until-after-a-command-line-script-completes) to MATLAB?

Comment: @Suever I want to run 1 and wait for it to finish then move on to 2, run 2 and wait for it to finish then move on to 3, then run 3

Comment: @ToniAz: Then you have to use the -wait parameter.

Comment: `start "My Title" /b /wait "c:\hello.exe"` First set of quotes are Window Title. Your file path is wrong. You'll need `/b` as well. See `start /?`. This is all you actually require `"c:\hello.exe"`.