# batch call matlab and ImageJ in sequential order

Tags: matlab, batch-file, execution

I am trying to get matlab and ImageJ work in a for loop in batch files.

The code is something like this

```
set iterationTimes=4

for /l %%i in (0,1,%iterationTimes%) do (

call matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "loop=%%i%%;"%stitchFile%

call %IJPath% -macro %JythonPath% %%arg%%

)
```

I specified the variable, the problem is ImageJ need to use the output of the matlab code, yet the batch seems execute ImageJ and Matlab in the same time...

I already used call to make the iteration variable i work, adding another call ahead of the two sentence would not help..

So how can I execute the matlab first and run ImageJ after matlab has finished running?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: update: I tried the start command, It works only partially. I call the matlab to run "loop=%%i%%" first, then run a .m file (stitchFile). when I add start /wait in front of the line, matlab only run the first line (loop = %%i%%) and stop..............

Comment: What are you doing with this code: `"loop=%%i%%;"`.  For variables are just referenced with two percent symbols before the letter.  You don't put two after.

Comment: I believe this is your problem.  You have to use [matlab's wait option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22307518/1417694). You should not have to use `START` or `CALL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to use [matlabs wait option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35687469/1417694). You do not use cmd.exe's `CALL` or `START /WAIT` commands.

```
set iterationTimes=4

for /l %%i in (0,1,%iterationTimes%) do (

matlab -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -r "loop=%%i;"%stitchFile%

call %IJPath% -macro %JythonPath% %%arg%%

)
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I literally have no experience in batch... I first wrote a bash code to do this and it works well both on OS X and Ubuntu... thus I did not think of this............

Comment: @HongliWang, it really wasn't a batch file problem.  You just were not using matlab correctly for the operating system you are using it on.