# Rstudio: how to stop a process with a system() line

Tags: r, matlab, rstudio

I have to run a matlab code inside R in a for loop like this

```
for (i in 1:d){
  system("matlab -nodisplay -r \"run('./ejemplolevina.m'); exit\"")
  intercep <- readMat("matlab2R_A.mat")
  pend <- readMat("matlab2R_B.mat")
  Theta0 <- intercep$A
  Theta1 <- pend$B
  Theta <- Theta0 + Theta1*X[i]
}
```

The MatLab script ejemplolevina.m gives me the outputs matlab2R_A.mat and matlab2R_B.mat which I have to use it after the system(...) command. The problem is when R runs the line

```
system("matlab -nodisplay -r \"run('./ejemplolevina.m'); exit\"")
```

it keeps going on with the rest, and it gives the error "matlab2R_A doesn't exist", because the script inside MatLab didn't finish yet. I need the for stops on system(...) and don't continue until Matlab is closed.

Comment: `while(!file.exists("matlab2R_A.mat')) sleep(1)` ?

Comment: (1) `system(..., wait=TRUE)` for the synchronous experience (I admit I'm a fan of async, but polling rapidly might not always be the best way). (2) Consider using the `processx` package instead, as `system` and `system2` are not without issues.

Comment: You probably have to use `-wait`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22307419/2732801

Comment: Thank you so much. The -wait worked perfectly